# Reset overlay button (cronjobs)

Tags: cron, crontab, magento-cron

Inside System > Scheduler > Job Configuration: then you click on a specific cronjob.

What does the button reset overlay do inside that panel?

**Magento ver. 1.14.1.0**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sets the schedule back to the original cron expression.
[image]